# Problems with Postgresql CASE syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions, case

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT (CASE (elapsed_time_from_first_login IS NULL) 
                        WHEN true THEN 0 
                        ELSE elapsed_time_from_first_login END) 
FROM (
   SELECT (now()::ABSTIME::INT4 - min(AcctStartTime)::ABSTIME::INT4) 
   FROM radacct
   WHERE UserName = 'test156') AS elapsed_time_from_first_login;
```

When I execute the above query, I get this error:

> ERROR:  CASE types record and integer cannot be matched

From the error message I understand that `PostgreSQL` take the second select, respectively `elapsed_time_from_first_login` as a row, even if it will always be a single value (because of the min() function).

**Question:** do you have some suggestions on how to deal with this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose, what you are actually trying to do should look like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT now() - min(acct_start_time)
                 FROM   radacct
                 WHERE  user_name = 'test156')
              , interval '0s')
```

While there is an aggregate function in the top `SELECT` list of the subselect, it cannot return "no row". The aggregate function `min()` converts "no row" to `NULL`, and the simple form below also does the trick.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=961496fd69969e327f587a8bd7f371de)*
<sub>Old[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/918ec/3)</sub>

Other problems with your query have already been pointed out. But this is the much simpler solution. It returns an `interval` rather than an `integer`.

#### Convert to integer

<sup>Simplified with input from artaxerxe.</sup>
Simple form does the job without check for "no row":

```
SELECT COALESCE(EXTRACT(epoch FROM now() - min(acct_start_time))::int, 0)
FROM   radacct
WHERE  user_name = 'test156';
```

Details about `EXTRACT(epoch FROM INTERVAL)` [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

#### Aggregate functions and `NULL`

If you had used the aggregate function `count()` instead of `sum()` as you had initially, the outcome would be different. `count()` is a special case among standard aggregate functions in that it never returns `NULL`. If no value (or row) is found, it returns `0` instead.

[The manual on aggregate functions:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

> It should be noted that except for `count`, these functions return a
> null value when no rows are selected. In particular, `sum` of no rows
> returns null, not zero as one might expect, and `array_agg` returns
> null rather than an empty array when there are no input rows. The
> coalesce function can be used to substitute zero or an empty array for
> null when necessary.

Comment: That's the shortest one, but it does not convert time to seconds. I need it as an amount of seconds. Do you have any better idea, assuming that `ABSTIME` is depracated? Thanks

Comment: @artaxerxe: I assumed that an `interval` would be the more appropriate type to measure time to begin with. I added a variant to get the count of seconds as `integer` instead.

Comment: @artaxerxe: I added a bit about aggregate functions and `NULL` that should be of interest in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres is complaining that `0` and `elapsed_time_from_first_login` are not the same type.

Try this (also simplifying your select):

```
select
    coalesce(elapsed_time_from_first_login::INT4, 0)
from ...
```

Comment: Not working! The error is still there! But Thanks anyway for tip.

Comment: I reversed the cast - try it now

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I formatted the `SQL` and now is working:

```
SELECT coalesce(result, 0) 
     FROM (SELECT (now()::ABSTIME::INT4 - min(AcctStartTime)::ABSTIME::INT4) as result 
                FROM radacct WHERE UserName = 'test156') as elapsed_time_from_first_login;
```

Comment: [Manual says](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html): _The types abstime and reltime are lower precision types which are used internally. You are discouraged from using these types in applications; these internal types might disappear in a future release._

Answer (score 1):

The second `SELECT` is returning a table, named `elapsed_time_from_first_login` with one column and one row. You have to alias that column and use it in the `CASE` clause. You can't put a whole table (even if it is one column, one row only) where a value is expected.

```
SELECT (CASE (elapsed_time IS NULL) 
                        WHEN true THEN 0 
                        ELSE elapsed_time end) 
   FROM (SELECT (now()::ABSTIME::INT4 - min(AcctStartTime)::ABSTIME::INT4) 
                AS elapsed_time                -- column alias
         FROM radacct 
         WHERE UserName = 'test156'
        ) as elapsed_time_from_first_login;    -- table alias
```

and you can shorten the `CASE` by using the `COALESCE()` function (and optionally add an alias for that column to be shown in the results):

```
SELECT COALESCE(elapsed_time, 0) 
         AS elapsed_time 
   FROM (SELECT (now()::ABSTIME::INT4 - min(AcctStartTime)::ABSTIME::INT4) 
                AS elapsed_time            
         FROM radacct 
         WHERE UserName = 'test156'
        ) as elapsed_time_from_first_login;    -- table alias
```

Comment: `COALESCE` will catch the case where `AcctStartTime IS NULL`, but will fail when there is no row in table `radacct` with UserName = 'test156'. I provided a solution for both cases. Then again, maybe the OP wants it that way. The question does not give any indication, really.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Actually it catches both situations.

Comment: @artaxerxe: Ah you are right! I overlooked the aggregate function, which turns "no row" into `NULL`. If you remove `min()` from the expression, the row goes away. [Quick test case on sqlfiddle to play with.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/918ec/3)